# No vulnerabilities reported on docker images in Artifact Registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

We've started to use Google Cloud Platform's Artifact Registry by pushing a couple of docker images.
Although the container scanning API was enabled successfully (`gcloud services enable containerscanning.googleapis.com --project=$PROJECT`) , we haven't seen any vulnerabilities being reported on any of the docker images. We have tried another vulnerability reporting tool and are sure there should be a couple of issues reported.

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: How long has it been since you enabled the service? Scanning is not instant. If the column for "Vulnerabilities" has a dash character, scanning has not yet happened. You can manually scan an image using the command: `gcloud beta artifacts docker images scan` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/artifacts/docker/images/scan

Comment: On-Demand scanning is not free: https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/pricing#ods

Comment: Could you please provide the commands used to scan the images? The following links might be useful for [on-demand scanning](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/on-demand-scanning#on-demand_scanning) and [docker vulnerability scan](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/get-image-vulnerabilities#view-gcloud)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.I found the reason in the Container Analysis API not being enabled, so I did
`gcloud services enable containeranalysis.googleapis.com --project=$PROJECT`
I just enabled the Container Scanning API at first.